# lmer Error: number of observations < number of random effects

Tags: lme4

I am trying to run an `LMM` allowing time to be a random effect:

```
lmer(efficacy ~ time + (1+time|id), data=long, REML=TRUE)
```

However, I get the error messageas below:

> Error: number of observations (=3948) <= number of random effects (=4496) for term (1 + time | id); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable

I have three time points but not all subjects have data for all 3 time points (attrition) but my missing count on my outcome variable (efficacy) only had 13 missing values and I have a total number of `3961 participants` in my entire data set. If anyone can shed some light on this or point me in the right direction I'd much appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume `time` is categorical, that's often a reason for this error. You may either convert `time` to numeric, or add this option to your `lmer()`-call: `control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore")`.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Daniel. Time was numeric unfortunately. I even tried using a separate time indicator (grade centered), which also gave me the same error. I did try the code you suggest and was able to get an output, but am wary as what I've read so far seem to indicate that the output may be flawed. Given the situation though, it might be the best I can hope for. Thanks again.