# "Number of observations <= number of random effects" error

Tags: r, mixed-models

I am using a package called `diagmeta` for meta-analysis purposes. I can use this package with a built in data set called `Schneider2017`. However when I make my own database/data set I get the following error:

> Error: number of observations (=300) <= number of random effects (=3074) for term (Group * Cutoff | Study); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable

Another thread here on SO suggests the error is caused by the data format of one or more columns. I have made sure every column's data type matches that in the `Schneider2017` dataset - no effect.

[Link to the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699081/lmer-error-number-of-observations-number-of-random-effects)

I have tried extracting all of the data from the Schneider2017 dataset into excel and then importing a dataset from Excel through R studio. This again makes no difference. This suggests to me that something in the data format could be different, although I can't see how.

```
diag2 <- diagmeta(tpos, fpos, tneg, fneg, cutpoint,
                   studlab = paste(author,year,group),
                   data = SRschneider,
                   model = "DIDS", log.cutoff = FALSE,
                   check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore")
```

The dataset looks like this: 
[image: This is what the dataset looks like]

I expected the same successful execution and plotting as with the built-in data set, but keep getting this error.

Result from doing str(mydataset):

```
> str(SRschneider)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   150 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ ...1    : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ study_id: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ author  : chr  "Arora" "Arora" "Arora" "Arora" ...
 $ year    : num  2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 ...
 $ group   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ cutpoint: chr  "6" "7.0" "8.0" "9.0" ...
 $ tpos    : num  133 131 130 127 119 115 113 110 102 98 ...
 $ fneg    : num  5 7 8 11 19 23 25 28 36 40 ...
 $ fpos    : num  34 33 31 30 28 26 25 21 19 19 ...
 $ tneg    : num  0 1 3 4 6 8 9 13 15 15 ...
```

Comment: A) can you provide an example of that data you are trying to place into `diagemta` through `dput`. A snap shot at a minimum would be helpful.
B) can you provide the output of `str(data)` with `data` being the new dataset you are trying to input?

Comment: Do you mean something different som the image of the dataset? That is what I'm trying to work on.
I have added the output from str(my dataset) now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you

> have made sure every column's data type matches that in the Schneider2017 dataset

but that doesn't seem to be true.  Besides differences between `num` (numeric) and `int` (integer) types (which actually aren't typically important), your data has

```
 $ cutpoint: chr  "6" "7.0" "8.0" "9.0" ...
```

while `str(Schneider2017)` has

```
 $ cutpoint: num  6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
```

Having your cutpoint be a character rather than numeric means that R will try to treat it as a categorical variable  (with many discrete levels).  This is very likely the source of your problem.

The `cutpoint` variable is likely a character because R encountered some value in this column that can't be interpreted as numeric (something as simple as a typographic error).  You can use `SRschneider$cutpoint <- as.numeric(SRschneider$cutpoint)` to convert the variable to numeric by brute force (values that can't be interpreted will be set to `NA`), but it would be better to go upstream and see where the problem is.

If you use tidyverse packages to load your data you should get a list of "parsing problems" that may be useful.  You can also try `cp <- SRschneider$cutpoint; cp[which(is.na(as.numeric(cp)))]` to look at the values that can't be converted.

Comment: I follow your reasoning. I will go through with what you suggest, but I suspect it won't fix the problem for the following reason:
This dataset is imported from excel and I haven't fixed the data formats.
Before this I had a version 1.0 of my own dataset - a dataframe made in R studio directly - and that's where i fixed the data format. So since it didn't help then, I suspect the error comes from some other matter.

Comment: Okay. Seeing no obvious typos in the 'cutpoint' column (which makes sense as it is copied for the working Schneider2017 dataset) I went ahead and fixed the format of the column.
This made it execute succesfully immediately. That is very good for my project but also curious.
My best guess is that the reason fixing the data format earlier ( in my first dataset) was that the dataset was too small at that point - so I've have two problems with the dataset both resulting in the same error.

Comment: The difference in the 'group' format was also a factor I suspected and fixed in my first dataset. But as it turns out it is working now in my 2nd dataset with the difference in format not resulting in an error.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick follow-up on Ben's detailed answer.

The statistical method implemented in `diagmeta()` expects that argument *cutpoint* is a continuous variable. We added a corresponding check for argument *cutpoint* (as well as arguments *TP*, *FP*, *TN*, and *FN*) in version 0.3-1 of R package **diagmeta**; see [commit in GitHub repository](https://github.com/guido-s/diagmeta/commit/8395d9886f70c9874fdc8e017fb2a14b0943746f) for technical details.

Accordingly, the following R commands will result in a more informative error message:

```
data(Schneider2017)
diagmeta(tpos, fpos, tneg, fneg, as.character(cutpoint),
         studlab = paste(author, year, group), data = Schneider2017)
```